# Conflict between fncychap and \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, incompatibility, fncychap

I could not find something similar, but please tell me if this is a dupliquate.

It seems that for some styles of the package `fncychap` do not allow one to use 
`\tableofcontents` (I am using book as the document is a dissertation). Indeed, compare

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

which works perfectly to me (as the styles `Sonny`, `Lenny`). However, when one changes the style to `Conny` (or `Glenn`, `Rejne`, `Bjarne`), I get many error messages, including `Missing number, treated as zero. \tableofcontents`.

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} 

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{First chapter}
 \end{document}
```

It there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from Ulrike Fischer.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} 

 \makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname}%
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother    

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{First chapter}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Do you have an explanation for this phenomenon? (By the way, this fix works too for all other styles, so this answer is complete).

Comment: No, I said in my answer that copy and paste from [https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer] Ulrike Fischer. His/her answer out from TeX.Sc.

Comment: I see, thank you again.

Comment: Sorry and Your welcome.